# Find IPv6 global scope address on Android device

Tags: android, ipv6

I am looking for a way to determine the global IPv6 address on my android device for testing purpose. Now, what I have obtained a list of interfaces from Android API as the following code:

```
NetworkInterface netInt: NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
```

`netInt` actually contains a list of all the interfaces on the devices. for example, as you can see from the following list..(just a part of the list)

```
[dummy0][2][/fe80::d878:d9ff:fe94:eeae%dummy0%2]
[rmnet_data0][7][/fe80::e03:fac6:8232:95d6%rmnet_data0%7]
                [/2607:fb90:543:e9dd:e03:fac6:8232:95d6%7%7]
```

I use some public IPv6 site and realized that my public IPv6 address is `2607:fb90:543:e9dd:e03:fac6:8232:95d6`. I would like to see if there is a reliable way to to extract `2607:fb90:543:e9dd:e03:fac6:8232:95d6%7%7` from the array since the index of the array changing all the time and from devices to devices.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to check for is that the first address word is 4 characters and the first character is a 2 or a 3.  If the array element meets those two conditions, it is a global address.  You can then clean up the surrounding garbage to get a valid address.

Note: IPv6 allows multiple global addresses to be assigned to an interface.  In fact, some OSes do that on purpose for security.

**Edit:**
The definition for an IPv6 Global Unicast address is `2000::/3`.  This yields `2000::` to `3ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`.  See: [IPv6 Global Unicast Address Assignments](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-unicast-address-assignments/ipv6-unicast-address-assignments.xhtml)

```
Note
The assignable Global Unicast Address space is defined in [RFC4291] as
being the address block defined by the prefix 2000::/3. All address
space in this block not listed in the table below is reserved by IANA
for future allocation.
```

IPv6 allows any number of IPv6 addresses on an interface, and you can use them as either incoming or outgoing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please show me where i can find the doc indicating an address starts with 2 or 3 as global address? Also, if we do have multiple public IPs, how do we know which one is for OUTGOING? I assume there is only one for outgoing. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help again. I did see the range of the Unicast address. Now i found two very similar ipv6 address as `2600:1010:b022:1349:d25c:f9bf:2881:d30c%3%3` and `2600:1010:8043"3aba:67ca:ac76:4a8f:dbdb%9%9`. I looked into the public ipv6 site and it told me the first one is the public ipv6 address. How do i identify each other?

Comment: I'm not completely sure about your Android version or how to tell which address is in use on Android, but Android supports Privacy Extensions.since version 4.0. Basically, you get a random interface (host) ID for the address, and the address will change periodically. The old address may hang around for a while. RFC 4941 describes Privacy Extensions: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4941